# Navigation bars in apps

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, settings

I recently noticed that the navigation bars on my iPhone changed and now a square is displayed around the icons. How do I change it back to normal?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72Afp.jpg)

I searched in the accessibility settings but didn’t find anything.